# Recalculate product price in WooCommerce based on a plugin's variable

Tags: woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have a product with variations I need to combine with a plugin that uploads a pdf file and gets its number of pages so once it's uploaded I need to multiply the number of pages by the selected variation. Also, when the variation changes the new price must be reflected in the product page. I'm modifiying the plugin's hook that triggers once the uploaded has finished but I can't find the way to recalculate the price.

I guess I have to change **add-to-cart-variation.js** but I don't know how to enable the number of pages from the backend to the front.